# Sum over defined Week limits

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, ssms

I have a rolling date with associated hours. I want to sum the hours over my defined 7-day week range of Saturday to Friday.

So I need to define any date as a week beginning Saturday, week ending Friday and sum over this range.

The table is in the form of:

| Date | Day | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-12 | Saturday | 3 |
| 2021-06-18 | Friday | 3 |
| 2021-06-21 | Monday | 1 |
| 2021-06-22 | Tuesday | 2 |

Grouping the above table into Saturday-Friday Week sums.

| Saturday | Friday | Total_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-12 | 2021-06-18 | 6 |
| 2021-06-19 | 2021-06-25 | 3 |

Comment: Which actual database... MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.  They have different date functions

Comment: SSMS, added the tag now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to tie this to `datepart()` or `datename()`, which in turn depends on `DATEFIRST` (alas!).

Instead, you can use date arithmetic.  This in turn depends on the fact that `0` date is a Monday.  But that is not configurable (as far as I know).

So:

```
select v.week as saturday, dateadd(day, 6, v.week) as friday,
       sum(hours)
from t cross apply
     (values (dateadd(day, 7*datediff(week, 0, dateadd(day, 1, t.date)) - 2, 0))
     ) v(week)
group by v.week
order by v.week;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13d61eaac3b47780b1baf57bf0fc1c03) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use date functions to get for each date (other than Saturday) the previous Saturday which is the start of the week it belongs too and group by that:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(dw, Date) % 7, Date) Saturday
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT Saturday,
       DATEADD(day, 6, Saturday) Friday, 
       SUM(Hours) Total_Hours
FROM cte
GROUP BY Saturday
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=47cfffebafa65a43116e20b0442e50a9).

This code works in SQL Server but similar logic and functions can be used for other databases.